# iMacros EVENT mode is malfunctioning during KEYPRESS

Tags: imacros

I have an iMacros code that copies content from one blog and posts the article image and article body content to my Facebook Wall post. Here is the working code:

```
VERSION BUILD=844 RECORDER=CR
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET URL http://www.marketwatch.com/story/too-early-to-tell-if-trump-bump-seen-in-jobs-numbers-economists-say-2017-03-10
URL GOTO={{URL}}
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=CLASS:article-image<SP>MG EXTRACT=HREF
SET IMG {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:article-body EXTRACT=TXT
SET BODY EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s=s.split('More from this Website')[0]; s;")
SET !EXTRACT NULL
URL GOTO=www.facebook.com
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:composerAudienceWrapper<SP>stat_elem<SP>_ej0
WAIT SECONDS=2
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="DIV[CLASS='_1mf _1mj']" CHARS="{{IMG}}"
WAIT SECONDS=5
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="DIV[CLASS='_1mf _1mj']" KEYS="[8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8]"
WAIT SECONDS=2
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="DIV[CLASS='_1mf _1mj']" CHARS="{{BODY}}"
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:u_0_15 ATTR=TXT:Post
WAIT SECONDS=2
```

At this line: `EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="DIV[CLASS='_1mf _1mj']" CHARS="{{IMG}}"` , when the code pastes the image URL into Facebook, it does the work halfway and it starts to mis-function - meaning it starts clicking some randone buttons on my facebook wall (while this line of code is still executing)...

Is there a solution to this issue?

Comment: 'iMacros for Firefox' seems to display a stable work in Event mode. Try to use it.

Comment: i did try it on 'iMacros for Firefox' too bud... same issue... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to paste a large piece of text, try to do this via clipboard, for example:

```
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET URL http://www.marketwatch.com/story/too-early-to-tell-if-trump-bump-seen-in-jobs-numbers-economists-say-2017-03-10
URL GOTO={{URL}}
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=CLASS:article-image<SP>MG EXTRACT=HREF
SET IMG {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:article-body EXTRACT=TXT
SET BODY EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s=s.split('More from this Website')[0]; s;")
SET !EXTRACT NULL
URL GOTO=www.facebook.com
WAIT SECONDS=2

SET !CLIPBOARD {{IMG}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=LABEL ATTR=TXT:"Choose a file to upload"
TAG POS=R1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:* EXTRACT=HTM
SET id EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/id="(.*?)"/)[1];")
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#{{id}}>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV" BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#{{id}}>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV" CHAR="v" MODIFIERS="ctrl"

' ...
```

Comment: yup buddy.. i tried this a few back and it works brilliant.. :) thanks again :)